# $g(x)$ continuous implies $f(x,y)=g(x)$ continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Is it true that if  $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined as $f(x,y)=g(x)$ where $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function then $f$ is also a continuous function? I tried it as follows

Let $(a,b)$ be any point of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $(x_{n},y_{n})\rightarrow(a,b),((x_{n},y_{n})\neq(a,b))$ then $x_{n}\rightarrow  a$ and hence $f(x_{n},y_{n})=g(x_{n})\rightarrow g(a)=f(a,b)$ so by sequential criterion $f$ is continuous at $(a,b).$ Please suggest me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Isn't it enough to use $|f(x,y)-f(a,b)|=|g(x)-g(a)|<\epsilon$ in the standard proof ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an other approach.

let $\epsilon$ be a real $>0$.

we have

$|f(x,y)-f(a,b)|=|g(x)-g(a)|$.

as $g$ is continuous at $a$,

there exists $\delta>0$ 
such that
if $ |x-a|<\delta$ then
$ |g(x)-g(a)|<\epsilon$.

now
if
$||(x,y)-(a,b)||=max(|x-a|,|y-b|)<\delta$

then

$|x-a|<\delta$ and $|f(x,y)-f(a,b)|<\epsilon$

this shows that $f$ is continuous at

each point $(a,b)$.

Comment: Yes its also more accurate....thanks a lot...